# Help me! How to make different version test in class exam

Tags: exam

I'm writing a test with class exam and have solution par question.

I use  `\NumberOfVersions{3}` to make three versions but I can complete. 
This a part of my code

```
  \documentclass[answers]{exam}

\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\usepackage{tabvar}

 \NumberOfVersions{1}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{answers}

      \renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Lời giải:}\enspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering{\large \textbf{Test }} }}}

\end{center}

\begin{questions}

\question compute $\displaystyle \int\limits_{1}^{e}\dfrac{\ln x}{x}dx$ 

\newline

\begin{oneparchoices}

\choice 1

\choice 3

\CorrectChoice $\dfrac{1}{2}$

\choice 0

\end{oneparchoices}

    \question For $\displaystyle \int f(x).\sin x dx= -f(x)\cos x+\int \cos 
x dx$ Find  $f(x)$

    \begin{choices}

        \begin{multicols}{4}

        \choice $f(x)=x$

        \CorrectChoice $f(x)=x+n $ với $n\in \mathbb{R}$

        \choice  $f(x)=x+1$

        \choice $f(x)=x^2-2$ 

        \end{multicols}

        \begin{solution}

        We have  $I=-\int f(x)d(\cos x)=-f(x)\cos x+\int \cos x dx \Longrightarrow f(x)=x+n$

        \end{solution}

\end{choices} 

    \question For $f(x)$ is consecutive function
 $[0,10]$ , known that $\displaystyle \int\limits_{0}^{10} f(x)dx =10$ and  $\displaystyle \int\limits_{2}^{6} f(x)dx=3$. compute $\displaystyle \int\limits_{0}^{2}f(x)dx +\int\limits_{6}^{10}f(x)dx=?$

    \newline

    \begin{oneparchoices}

    \choice 1

    \choice 3

    \CorrectChoice 7

    \choice  8 

    \end{oneparchoices}

    \begin{solution}
    We have: 
    \end{solution}
 \end{questions}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: `\NumberOfVersions` is an [`examdesign`](http://ctan.org/pkg/examdesign) class command while you are using [`exam`](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam) class. I think `exam` cannot produce different versions like `examdesign`.

Comment: Can you help me to produce different version with exam class?

Comment: @Ignasi I used `exam` for quite some time and I also don't recall ever reading about such a functionality. Also, I think I remember questions are a group.

Comment: No. If `exam` doesn't have mechanisms for different versions is difficult to do it. But there exist other document classes which do it for you. You can start investigating [in CTAN](http://ctan.org/topic/exam). It seems that, at least, `examdesign` or `esami` can do it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question this morning. The following Python code will accomplish the goal. I copied only my `\question`'s to a new file, inserted string `%%%` between the questions, and it wrote a shuffled set of questions into the new file which I then `\input{}` into my LaTeX exam between `\begin{questions}` ... `\end{questions}`.

```
import random

with open('original_questions.txt', 'r') as file:
    questions = file.read().split('%%%')
random.shuffle(questions)
with open('shuffled_questions.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('%%%'.join(questions))
```

Comment: Thanks - updated to add "Python" before "code" above.